# Метод get_next_by_FOO неправильно выдает ссылку

Tags: django, веб-программирование, backend

Проблема моя в том, что я указываю метод get_next_by_FOO, но ссылка работает неправильно.

#models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE, db_index=True)
    name = CharField(_("Название проекта"), max_length=150, db_index=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(
        _("Обложка"), upload_to="project_photos/", null=True, blank=True
    )
    site = URLField(_("Ссылка на сайт проекта"), max_length=200)
    description = TextField(_("Описание продукта/сервиса"))
    note = CharField(_("Примечание к проекту"), max_length=150)
    created_at = DateTimeField(_("Время создания"), auto_now_add=True)


    def next(self):
        return self.get_next_by_created_at()

    def pre(self):
        return self.get_previous_by_created_at()
```

#html

```
    <a href="{{ project.next }}">Следующий</a>
    <a href="{{ project.pre }}">Предыдущий</a>
```

И выдает следующую ссылку : http://localhost:8000/projects/8/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Т.е. id модели не меняется, а к концу ссылки добавляется имя следующего или предыдущего экзмепляра модели

Comment: Так вы здесь не сделали никакую ссылку, вы просто получили объект и воткнули его куда попало, естественно получилась белиберда

Comment: вам нужно указать в `a` `{% url '<url_name>' project.next.pk %}` как вариант

Comment: @ZaArs 
<a href="{% url 'project_detail_url' project.next.pk %}">Следующий</a>
 <a href="{% url 'project_detail_url' project.pre.pk %}">Предыдущий</a> 

получилось, все работает. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="{% url 'project_detail_url' project.next.pk %}">Следующий</a>
<a href="{% url 'project_detail_url' project.pre.pk %}">Предыдущий</a>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]